# ssl channel wcf web api?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, wcf-web-api

I'm currently developing a web api, with WCF web api, which allows me to write restful apis. One concern I have is security. For this reason I decided to protect my api with the OAuth protocol which works very good. However, the team got to the conclusion that our own applications shouldn't be authorized by oauth, instead they sould be authorized by http basic, meaning that the client application should send username and password.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I set up WCF Web Api to work with SSL, I'm using Web Api preview 6, and the project is a MVC3 application?
2. I have an operation handler which takes care of the creation of IPrincipal from the client access token, and then injects it into the operation parameters, so I can access the user's info. I would like to have in the same operation handler a condition where I could check if the authorization scheme is OAuth or http basic, and then in the case of http basic extract the user's credentials and authenticate that specific user against my data base, if authentication is successful create an IPrincipal and inject it to the operation parameters. However, as I see it, everytime an application using http basic requests something to the api, I would have to go to the data base and authenticate. So my question is: Am I in the right path, or this could be accomplished in some other way?

Any answers would be appreciate it. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You setup SSL for WCF Web API just like you would any other WCF service exposed over HTTPS. If you are hosted in IIS, then you need to configure a site binding for HTTPS. If you are self hosted, then the configuration is bit more involved. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx for all of the details.

To handle basic auth against a custom identity provider you would typically use a custom authz module when hosted in IIS. See [http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/] for an example of how to do this. If you are self hosted then you can use a custom username passworld validator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx for details.

Yes, I believe you are correct that every request will require authentication unless you establish some sort of session-like semantics.

Hope this helps.